# The padding with border radius overlaps the image inside

Tags: html, css

I have an `<img>` and I'm giving it a `background-color`, a `padding` along with a `border-radius`.

The problem is that even though I have a padding and so there's a lot of space between the inner image and the edges of the box, the `border-radius` apparently gets applied to the image inside as well, and therefore causes the edges of the inner image to be cut off. Here's what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYKfh.png

```css
.element img {
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #6e4fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/L8JEkBk.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: While jsFiddle is very convenient, here we also like to see source code in plaint text in the question. Please take a moment to read this guide [ask]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the styling to the parent element, take out the padding, and center with flexbox:

```css
.valueelement {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #6e4fff;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.valueelement img{
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="valueelement">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/L8JEkBk.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML. You don't need flexbox to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `calc` method when positioning your image in conjunction with `display:block` and `position:absolute`. Formula: calc(`50% - imageWidth/2`), then do the same for the height.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h867qgcL/

```css
.valueelement {
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #6e4fff;
  height: 80px;
  min-width:80px;
  width:80px;
}

.valueelement img {
  position: absolute;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 13px);
  margin-top:calc(50% - 15px);
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="valueelement">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/L8JEkBk.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That's still not that, as same I might change the border-radius to 30%, but I want the background to be circle still. This change just makes the background become more cube-like.

Comment: The HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as a closing tag for `<img>`

Comment: @Rob Wow... Thats what I get for using just pasting OPs html-code, just focused on the CSS. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```css
.valueelement img { 
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.valueelement {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #6e4fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="valueelement">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/L8JEkBk.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: image not centered.

Comment: @Joel . Yep. I Applied the fixes

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob They are NOT necessary for HTML but they are necessary for XHTML and are harmless in HTML. For me, it is kind of habit putting it at the end of all `void`  tags like `img`

Comment: You, and he, are not using XHTML so putting them there is superfluous. The only reason they are allowed is to not break old web sites that used XHTML/XML. Otherwise, putting them there is not specified or called for in any HTML specification or examples in those specifications. It does nothing, it has no meaning, browsers are instructed to ignore it and, therefore, it is pointless and useless.